# CWAC-camera fragment fill screen

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

Is there any possibility to achieve full screen camera preview using [CWAC-camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera)?
Because now I am getting this:

[image]

Even without actionbar there are thiner blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the aspect ratio of the preview needs to match the aspect ratio of the picture that you are going to take, otherwise your pictures get stretched or squashed.

If I find a workaround for that, then perhaps you will be able to get edge-to-edge previews. Right now, the preview automatically changes its aspect ratio.

Comment: so there is no way to achieve edge-to-edge preview right now? Then how it works in native camera app?

Comment: @Geralt_Encore: You are welcome to make sense of the native camera app's source code and find out.

Comment: Note that full-bleed preview support has been added to the library.

Comment: I just want to added, that native camera app does not always full screen, it depends on the ratio of screen and ratio of preview/picture you picked.  Usually screen are 16:9 or 16:10.  If you pick 16:9 picture, it will be full screen.  If you pick 4:3, there will be black area on bottom (portrait)/right side(landscape).

Answer (score 0):

@Geralt_Encore

if you still want it to be fill screen then you should make some changes in onLayout() method of CameraView

comment the below code

```
 if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
        final int scaledChildWidth=
            previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
        child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                     (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
      }
      else {
        final int scaledChildHeight=
            previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
        child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width,
                     (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
      }
```

and add this line instead of above code

```
child.layout(l,t,r,b);
```

and you are done. now you will get full screen preview 
it will work but i haven't tested it with orientation changes because i Want my Camera Activity to be in portrait mode only.

hope this will help you

Comment: When adding the code above my image was stretched a bit in portrait mode